# Silverlight .xap zip/unzip problems

Tags: .net, silverlight, iis, powershell, xap

I'm working on powershell script that should change endpoint configuration within ServiceReference.ClientConfig, but today i encountered a problem:
when i extract all `xap` content (as i know `xap` - renamed `zip` archive) in a temporary folder, doing all work with config, and zip it back, silverlight preloader does not load application(hosted in IIS). It does not load if i even simply unzip and zip (using WinRar/7Zip) it back.
But if i open `xap` using `WinRar` and do all changes without unzipping content in temporary folder it works fine.

maybe somebody know any info/workarounds about this issue?

p.s.
couple of lines of code that i use (powershell)

```
expand-archive -path $xapPackagePath -outputpath $xapExpandedTmpPath -force
write-zip -path (gci ($xapExpandedTmpPath + "\") -rec) -outputpath ($xapPackagepath)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if it's an issue with the specific type of zip compression you are using when re-zipping it.

You could have a look at this article for a suggested way of creating xap with code:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/67d9ce4d-285c-42ee-b4e0-d5640ca4f6a6/